# Get the left sidebar background to extend all the way left

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed 960px layout with a light-gray sidebar and a white everything else. I want the content of the site centered within the 960px layout, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the background of the sidebar to extend all the way to the left of the page with css. Any ideas?

[Here's a photoshop mock of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoFoo.png)

Comment: So you want to always have the entire left side of the page have a gray background? In other words, from the left side of the window, to the beginning of the left sidebar, no matter how big the user's window size?

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

in your css

```
body {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
```

style your side bar with no left margin and define the width.

Best i can do without seeing the code.